# How do I print a list of nodes at a specific level of a general tree?

Tags: haskell

I am given the following tree definition and functions:

```
data Tree a = Node a [Tree a] deriving (Eq, Read, Show)

treeRoot :: Tree a -> a
treeRoot (Node a _) = a

treeSubtrees :: Tree a -> [Tree a]
treeSubtrees (Node _ subtrees) = subtrees
```

I need to create a function 'nodesAtLevel' that takes two arguments: a tree and an integer n >= 0. The function needs to return a list of all the nodes at the given level n. The root of the tree is level 0. I am very new to Haskell, and yes, this is part of a homework assignment, so if you could help walk me through the thought process of completing this, it would be greatly appreciated! I currently have the definition of the 'nodesAtLevel' function written as follows:

```
nodesAtLevel :: Int -> Tree a -> [a]
```

Comment: Okay, next step: try implementing `nodesAtLevel 0`. Then, write `nodesAtLevel n` in function of `nodesAtLevel (n-1)`.

Comment: Stack overflow isn't a great venue for "how do I write this from scratch" sort of questions.  I suggest you attempt to implement the function you're asking about then when you get stuck ask about that particular sub-problem.

Comment: if you like you can try my answer - I will try to answer comments/questions on it without spoiling to much and come back later to fill in the holes (to make a complete answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, let's to this step by step (leaving you with some holes for now):

### nodes at level 0

as I understand it you are suppost to only return the roots value here (of course in a list)

so what goes in the `...` here?

```
nodesAtLevel 0 (Node a subtrees) = ...
```

### nodes at deeper levels

well the structure is nicely recursive so we probably want to use recursion.

So let's go recursively deeper one level deeper (decreasing the *way we have left to go* - aka our `n`)

But there is a slight problem: `nodesAtLevel` acts on a single node but we only have a list of nodes left (the `subtrees`) .. so what to do?

Well maybe we should do something *for each* of the subtrees/subnodes - so we need to find the right function `f` here (*hint* you probably want to *map* and *concat* the results ...):

```
nodesAtLevel n (Node a subtrees) = f (nodesAtLevel (n-1)) subtrees
```

what can that `f` be? Can you guess it? Maybe you can write it yourself if not?

---

#### Additional Hint:

maybe you should first find out what *type* `f` has - because then you might be even able to use [Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) to find a good fit.

If you use a newer GHC version you an let the compiler do the work if you write

```
nodesAtLevel n (Node _ subtrees) = _f (nodesAtLevel (n-1)) subtrees
```

where `_f` is a **hole** - now if you load this in GHCi it will give you a

```
Found hole ‘_f’ with type: ....
```

error with lot's of additional information ;)

---

so just find `...` and `f` and this should work ;)

**BTW** you can use the functions you already have instead of *pattern matching* again as I did, but I feel it's easier to see the result this way - so if you follow this *path* you don't need to use `treeSubtrees` or `treeRoot`

---

### solution

- `...` = `[a]`
- `f` = [`concatMap`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:concatMap)

so one possible way to do it is this:

```
nodesAtLevel :: Int -> Tree a -> [a]
nodesAtLevel 0 (Node a _) = [a]
nodesAtLevel n (Node _ subtrees) = concatMap (nodesAtLevel (n-1)) subtrees
```